# xslt listing unbounded elements

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to prepare an xslt file to print my xml list, however I am having difficulties. I have almost finished the entire project, but my problem is that I have unbounded elements which may appear more than one time in my xml file, for instance I have exterior_color element which is unbounded and appears in xml file many times, when I list the entire xml the below there is no such issue, but it is not listing other exterior_color elements which is mandatory. I am missing something but i dont know what. Thanks for your assistance in advance

**car_dealer.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <car_dealer>

<car>
    <year>2013</year>
    <make>Ford</make>
    <model>Mustang</model>
    <transmission>Manual</transmission>
    <exterior_color>Red</exterior_color>
    <cylinders>8</cylinders>
    <fuel type="fluid">Diesel</fuel>
    <fuel type="gas">LPG</fuel>
    <doors>4</doors>
    <warranty>true</warranty>
    <description>Car</description>
</car>

    <car>
    <year>1995</year>
    <make>Ford</make>
    <model>Mustang</model>
    <transmission>Manual</transmission>
    <exterior_color>Red</exterior_color>
    <exterior_color>Blue</exterior_color>
    <cylinders>8</cylinders>
    <fuel type="fluid">Diesel</fuel>
    <doors>4</doors>
    <warranty>true</warranty>
    <description>Car</description>
</car>
 </car_dealer>
```

**car_dealer.xslt**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>

    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
      <body>
        <h2>Car Dealers</h2>
        <table border="1">
          <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th>Year</th>
            <th>Make</th>
            <th>Model</th>
            <th>Transmission</th>
            <th>Exterior Color</th>
            <th>Cylinders</th>
            <th>Fuel</th>
            <th>Doors</th>
            <th>Warranty</th>
            <th>Description</th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:for-each select="car_dealer/car">
          <xsl:sort order="ascending" select="year"/>
            <tr>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="year"/></td>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="make"/></td>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="model"/></td>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="transmission"/></td>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="exterior_color"/></td>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="cylinders"/></td>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="fuel"/><br />Type:<xsl:value-of select="fuel/@type"/> </td>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="doors"/></td>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="warranty"/></td>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="description"/></td>
            </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
      </body>
      </html>
    </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing **xsl:value-of** will only return the value of the first element in this case. What you should do is replace it with an **xsl:apply-templates**

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="exterior_color"/>
```

Then have a template that matches **exterior_color** where you can output the value

```
<xsl:template match="exterior_color">
   <xsl:value-of select="." />
   <br />
</xsl:template>
```

Or if you didn't want a new line after the last colour, you could do this

```
<xsl:template match="exterior_color">
  <xsl:if test="position() > 1">
         <br />
   </xsl:if>
   <xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:template>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
      <body>
        <h2>Car Dealers</h2>
        <table border="1">
          <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th>Year</th>
            <th>Make</th>
            <th>Model</th>
            <th>Transmission</th>
            <th>Exterior Color</th>
            <th>Cylinders</th>
            <th>Fuel</th>
            <th>Doors</th>
            <th>Warranty</th>
            <th>Description</th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:for-each select="car_dealer/car">
          <xsl:sort order="ascending" select="year"/>
            <tr>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="year"/></td>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="make"/></td>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="model"/></td>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="transmission"/></td>
              <td><xsl:apply-templates select="exterior_color"/></td>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="cylinders"/></td>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="fuel"/><br />Type:<xsl:value-of select="fuel/@type"/> </td>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="doors"/></td>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="warranty"/></td>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="description"/></td>
            </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
      </body>
      </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="exterior_color">
      <xsl:if test="position() > 1">
             <br />
       </xsl:if>
       <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Tim! you have saved 2 days for me!! I could not imagine the apply theme themes one in my head! more question what if I apply the same thing to the fuel element? fuel element has attributes and I tried to do it with the element fuel and acquire its attribute but did not work on me

Comment: You should be able to do the same thing with the "fuel" element. You will just need do bear in mind that within the template that matches "fuel", you would get the value of the attribute by simply doing `<xsl:value-of select="@type">` because your context is now the fuel "element", not the "car" element.

Comment: according to your advise I have re altered  my code lines works like a charm, thank you very much for your prompt help and saving my day Tim!